# How to append some text to DisplayMember of a Control

Tags: c#, ado.net, listbox, datasource, bindingsource

How can I add some text or other Fields at the end of `DisplayMember` without changing `DataSource`

```
this.lstSubjects.DataSource = this.subjectBindingSource;
this.lstSubjects.DisplayMember = "Caption";
this.lstSubjects.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.lstSubjects.Name = "lstSubjects";
this.lstSubjects.ValueMember = "SubjectCode";
this.lstSubjects.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.lstSubjects_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

For example, I want to display both `Caption` and `SubjectCode` Fields of DataTable in each listbox row, However Value of each row would be `SubjectCode`

I want something like this:

*ListBox's DisplayMember = "Technology (AD)"*

*ListBox's Value = "AD"*

thanks in advance,

Comment: you want to make a new member for displaying the text you want

Comment: I want to show two datatable's fields as one member for DisplayMember; is it possible?

Comment: you can always create i list of the combination of them...
even better, when doing the query you can create a field that will be the combination

Comment: if you mean I should change the query, I've used that query multiple times, so maybe I have to write a new query. but I'm looking for a better way, if it is a better way

Answer (score 2):

First, you can leave your DisplayMember with one property, let's say:

```
lstSubjects.DisplayMember = "lastname";
```

Now, go to your form in a [Design] mode, right click on the ListBox -> Properties.

In the top of the Properties window, click on Events (lightning icon),

look for Format in the events list below (under Property Changed) and type there some event name, let's say: lstSubjectsFormat , and press Enter. You will see this:

```
private void lstSubjectsFormat(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{

}
```

And now write these following lines inside:

```
private void lstSubjectsFormat(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming your class called Employee , and Firstname & Lastname are the fields
    string lastname = ((Employee)e.ListItem).Firstname;
    string firstname = ((Employee)e.ListItem).Lastname;
    e.Value = lastname + " " + firstname;
}
```

That's it ;)

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Must set FormattingEnabled = true for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

i have it for you. as i understand you are doing an sql query to get your data.
use [this](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090310033152AAzxLYz) to make your query contain the string you need.
for example if your table contains two varchar fields you can do

```
SELECT column1 +'(' + column2 + ')' FROM myTable;
```

that is the best way to do it, and also the right way to do it and it took me some time to find it...